# unittest and metaclass: automatic test_* method generation

Tags: python, unit-testing, metaclass

As I create tests for a framework, I start noticing the following pattern:

```
class SomeTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_feat_true(self):
        _test_feat(self, True)

    def test_feat_false(self):
        _test_feat(self, False)

    def _test_feat(self, arg):
        pass    # test logic goes here
```

So I want to programmatically create `test_feat_*` methods for these type of test classes with a metaclass. In other words, for each private method with signature `_test_{featname}(self, arg)`, I want two top-level, discoverable methods with the signatures `test_{featname}_true(self)` and `test_{featname}_false(self)` to be created.

I came up with something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import unittest


class TestMaker(type):

    def __new__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        callables = dict([
            (meth_name, meth) for (meth_name, meth) in attrs.items() if
            meth_name.startswith('_test')
        ])

        for meth_name, meth in callables.items():
            assert callable(meth)
            _, _, testname = meth_name.partition('_test')

            # inject methods: test{testname}_{[false,true]}(self)
            for suffix, arg in (('false', False), ('true', True)):
                testable_name = 'test{0}{1}'.format(testname, suffix)
                attrs[testable_name] = lambda self: meth(self, arg)

        return type.__new__(cls, name, bases, attrs)


class TestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    __metaclass__ = TestMaker

    def _test_this(self, arg):
        print 'this: ' + str(arg)

    def _test_that(self, arg):
        print 'that: ' + str(arg)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

I expect some output like:

```
this: False
this: True
that: False
that: True
```

But what I got is:

```
$ ./test_meta.py
that: True
.that: True
.that: True
.that: True
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 4 tests in 0.000s

OK
```

It looks like there are some closure rules that I am missing. How do I get around this? Is there a better approach?

Thanks,

*edit*: Fixed. See: [the snippet](https://gist.github.com/852268/e8430a8322c25c39fbd5cd18b84d21d2b26b9be8).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Indeed, it is a closure issue:

Change

```
attrs[testable_name] = lambda self: meth(self, arg)
```

to

```
attrs[testable_name] = lambda self,meth=meth,arg=arg: meth(self, arg)
```

By using a default value, `arg` inside the lambda is bound to the default value `arg` set during each iteration of the loop. Without the default value, `arg` takes on the last value of `arg` after all the iterations of the loop have completed. (And the same goes for `meth`).

Comment: Hm, actually, the `meth` function also takes on the last function of the iteration. Fixable using the same trick.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than going the metaclass route I would look into using nose test generators for this sort of thing:

http://somethingaboutorange.com/mrl/projects/nose/1.0.0/writing_tests.html#test-generators

The downside of test generators is that they are a nose specific feature, so you need to introduce a dependency outside the stdlib.  The upside is that I think they are easier to write and understand.

Comment: Well, what do you know. I *am* using nose! I distilled it down to the bare stdlib code to show what problem I am trying to solve. I didn't know such feature in nose exists, though. I'll check it out. Thanks!

Comment: Ah, blast! Note: "Please note that method generators are not supported in `unittest.TestCase` subclasses." I need to rely on fixtures defined in a tree of those subclasses.