# nose, unittest.TestCase and metaclass: auto-generated test_* methods not discovered

Tags: python, unit-testing, metaclass, nose

This is a follow-up question for [unittest and metaclass: automatic test_* method generation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5175942/unittest-and-metaclass-automatic-test-method-generation):

For this (fixed) unittest.TestCase layout:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import unittest


class TestMaker(type):

    def __new__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        callables = dict([
            (meth_name, meth) for (meth_name, meth) in attrs.items() if
            meth_name.startswith('_test')
        ])

        for meth_name, meth in callables.items():
            assert callable(meth)
            _, _, testname = meth_name.partition('_test')

            # inject methods: test{testname}_v4,6(self)
            for suffix, arg in (('_false', False), ('_true', True)):
                testable_name = 'test{0}{1}'.format(testname, suffix)
                testable = lambda self, func=meth, arg=arg: func(self, arg)
                attrs[testable_name] = testable

        return type.__new__(cls, name, bases, attrs)


class TestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    __metaclass__ = TestMaker

    def test_normal(self):
        print 'Hello from ' + self.id()

    def _test_this(self, arg):
        print '[{0}] this: {1}'.format(self.id(), str(arg))

    def _test_that(self, arg):
        print '[{0}] that: {1}'.format(self.id(), str(arg))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

This works using `stdlib`'s framework. Expected and actual output:

```
C:\Users\santa4nt\Desktop>C:\Python27\python.exe test_meta.py
Hello from __main__.TestCase.test_normal
.[__main__.TestCase.test_that_false] that: False
.[__main__.TestCase.test_that_true] that: True
.[__main__.TestCase.test_this_false] this: False
.[__main__.TestCase.test_this_true] this: True
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 5 tests in 0.015s

OK
```

However, since I am actually using [nose](http://somethingaboutorange.com/mrl/projects/nose/1.0.0/), this trick seems to not agree with it. The output I got is:

```
C:\Users\santa4nt\Desktop>C:\Python27\python.exe C:\Python27\Scripts\nosetests test_meta.py
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

OK
```

In short, the `test_*` methods generated by the metaclass do not register with [nose](http://somethingaboutorange.com/mrl/projects/nose/1.0.0/). Can anyone shed a light on this?

Thanks,

Comment: Have a look at http://ivory.idyll.org/articles/nose-intro.html#a-somewhat-more-complete-guide-to-test-discovery-and-execution. Running with `-vv` may give you the info you need.

Comment: Also look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/347574/how-do-i-get-nose-to-discover-dynamically-generated-testcases

Comment: Well, what do you know, someone was trying to do something similar. I have looked at nose's test generator, though, but unfortunately it doesn't support test classes derived from `unittest.TestCase` and I need fixtures defined in a subclass trees of that.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

So, after sleuthing through both stdlib's `unittest` and nose's loader and selector source code, it turns out that nose overrides `unittest.TestLoader.getTestCaseNames` to use its own selector (with plugin points).

Now, nose's selector looks for a potential method's `method.__name__` to match certain regexes, black and white lists, and plugins' decisions.

In my case, the dynamically generated functions have its `testable.__name__ == '<lambda>'`, matching none of nose's selector criteria.

To fix,

```
        # inject methods: test{testname}_v4,6(self)
        for suffix, arg in (('_false', False), ('_true', True)):
            testable_name = 'test{0}{1}'.format(testname, suffix)
            testable = lambda self, arg=arg: meth(self, arg)
            testable.__name__ = testable_name    # XXX: the fix
            attrs[testable_name] = testable
```

And sure enough:

```
(sandbox-2.7)bash-3.2$ nosetests -vv 
test_normal (test_testgen.TestCase) ... ok
test_that_false (test_testgen.TestCase) ... ok
test_that_true (test_testgen.TestCase) ... ok
test_this_false (test_testgen.TestCase) ... ok
test_this_true (test_testgen.TestCase) ... ok

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 5 tests in 0.005s

OK
```